# Memory stream closed?

Tags: c#, serialization, stream

How did the MemoryStream close when it has not reached the end of its using statement?

```
MusicDataStore musicData = MusicDataStore.TestData();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
      formatter.Serialize(memStream, musicData);

      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memStream))
      {
           memStream.Position = 0;
           Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
      }

      //deserialize
      memStream.Position = 0;
      MusicDataStore input = (MusicDataStore)formatter.Deserialize(memStream);

  }
```

I should be able to deserialize the memStream but it cannot be read because it is closed.

When I tried removing the StreamReader block I can successfully deserialize the memStream. Why? What's happening to memStream in StreamReader block?

Comment: Side note: unless you're *really careful*, using `BinaryFormatter` is usually *not* a good choice for most people. I work in serialization **a lot** (seriously, lots) - and the number of times I've seen people get burned by `BinaryFormatter` is ... too many. If you are *able* to choose a different serialization tool, I strongly advise it. Happy to advise on options too.

Comment: additional additional: `StreamReader` and `ReadToEnd()` on a binary payload ... isn't actually a useful operation; as long as you're only doing that to check that something was written: fine - but - don't ever try to do anything with that `string` : it is already irreparably broken when you try to read it as a `string`, because it isn't text data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StreamReader takes ownership of the Stream it's given, and will close it when it is disposed (most of the types which take another `IDisposable` type in their constructor will do this).

[This StreamReader constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) takes a boolean saying whether to leave the stream open after the StreamReader is disposed as its last parameter:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(memStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
{
    ...
}
```

(Those other parameters are the defaults which `StreamReader(Stream)` uses, from [the referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,133).)

As Marc Gravell rightly notes in the comments, we've said to use UTF-8 encoding, but it looks like your stream is binary and definitely not UTF-8 text! So expect this to fail in practice. It may be more useful to look at the output of `BitConverter.ToString(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memStream.Length)` (or more simply but less efficiently `BitConverter.ToString(memStream.ToArray())`).